# Sending UDP requests through Tor (SOCKS5) with Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, tor

So I have a python script that needs to send a packet to my server 'x.x.x.x'. I've been able to successfully initialise Tor through Python by setting up the SOCKS5 proxy, but upon trying to send a packet to my server I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
sock.sendto(bytes, ("x.x.x.x", 6000))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 338, in sendto
self.bind(("", 0))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 325, in bind
_, relay = self._SOCKS5_request(self._proxyconn, UDP_ASSOCIATE, dst)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 494, in _SOCKS5_request
raise SOCKS5Error("{0:#04x}: {1}".format(status, error))
socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x07: Command not supported, or protocol error
```

From what I've seen, socket/SOCKS5 doesn't support connectionless UDP, so I attempted connecting to the port and then sending the packet once connected. I still get the same error as seen above, output can be seen below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
sock.connect(("x.x.x.x", 6000))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 698, in connect
self.bind(("", 0))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 325, in bind
_, relay = self._SOCKS5_request(self._proxyconn, UDP_ASSOCIATE, dst)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 494, in _SOCKS5_request
raise SOCKS5Error("{0:#04x}: {1}".format(status, error))
socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x07: Command not supported, or protocol error
```

Seeing as a UDP connection does not work either, I would prefer to stay connectionless as this makes my intended use simpler as the port is not necessarily active/open at any given time. The script I'm using to attempt to send the packet can be seen below. I've added but commented out the connectionless and connection methods I was using. Ignore all the extra imports at the top, these are for use later in the script development.

```
import socks
import socket
import requests
from TorCtl import TorCtl
import urllib2
import random
import math
import time

socks.setdefaultproxy(proxy_type=socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, addr="127.0.0.1", port=9050)

socket.socket = socks.socksocket

print requests.get("http://icanhazip.com").text

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bytes=random._urandom(1024)

# UDP CONNECTION METHOD
#sock.connect(("x.x.x.x", 6000))
#sock.send(bytes)

# UDP CONNECTIONLESS METHOD
#sock.sendto(bytes, ("x.x.x.x", 6000))
```

Which brings me to my question - is there any way to send UDP packets via a connectionless method through a SOCKS5 proxy in python?

**UPDATE**

I originally had `SocksiPy` installed instead of `PySocks`, so I've replaced the modules and removed the monkeypatch in the original script. But now, I'm instead getting 'Broken Pipe' errors, as seen below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
s.sendto(bytes, ("x.x.x.x", 6000))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 336, in sendto
return _BaseSocket.sendto(self, bytes, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 223, in <lambda>
return lambda self, *pos, **kw: self._savedmethods[name](*pos, **kw)
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I've double checked to make sure Tor is actually working and the proxy is up, which it is as I can receive HTTP requests and responses through the Tor proxy - the responses to sites like `http://icanhazip.com/` return a different IP that my actual IP, which suggests that Tor is indeed functioning. I also figured that removing the monkeypatch might make it work with better compatibility, seeing as with the new `PySocks` module on the **OLD** script it still fails with the original errors seen above.

The new script:

```
import socks
import socket
import random
import math

s = socks.socksocket()
s.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 9050)

bytes=random._urandom(1024)

# UDP CONNECTION METHOD
#sock.connect(("x.x.x.x", 6000))
#sock.send(bytes)

# UDP CONNECTIONLESS METHOD
#s.sendto(bytes, ("x.x.x.x", 6000))
```

The errors I'm describing above are with the connectionless method - using the connection method seems to possibly work, however it hangs when connecting to the port (which is the be expected, as the port isn't open).

Comment: Doesn't look like that socks module you have supports UDP port binding over SOCKS, but there is a fork of it [here](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks) which does, though it doesn't provide any great example.  But I checked the code and it does support the SOCKS command for binding UDP ports which the original did not.

Comment: I originally thought I had PySocks, but turns out I did have the original SocksiPy module. I've removed SocksiPy and replaced it with PySocks - instead of "Command not supported" errors, I'm now getting "Broken Pipe" errors. See the update in the main question for the logs, etc.

Comment: As far as I know, "[Tor only works for TCP streams](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en)", not UDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gwyn pointed out, Tor only supports TCP streams, [as specified on their website](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en). Using UDP over Tor will not work, only TCP connections.